# TimeoutException: Timeout of 60000ms expired before the position for partition could be determined when I try to read from kafka to flink

Tags: apache-kafka, docker-compose, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I'm trying to read records from a topic in Kafka which is produced by a kafka connect jdbc source connector , here is the connector config:

```
"name": "customers",
"config": {
    "poll.interval.ms": "3000",
    "table.poll.interval.ms": "10000",
    "errors.log.enable": "false",
    "errors.log.include.messages": "false",
    "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector",
    "topic.prefix": "_",
    "mode": "incrementing",
    "validate.non.null": "true",
    "table.whitelist": "customers",
    "incrementing.column.name": "customer_id",
    "connection.url": "jdbc:sqlserver://demo-sqlserver:1433;databaseName=DemoData",
    "connection.user": "sa",
    "connection.password": "password",
    "key.converter": "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
    "key.converter.schema.registry.url": "http://kafka-schema-registry:8081",
    "value.converter": "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
    "value.converter.schema.registry.url": "http://kafka-schema-registry:8081",
    "tasks.max": "2"
}
```

I'm using docker-compose to run kafka stack containers with this images:
zookeeper:3.4.9, confluentinc/cp-kafka:5.5.1, confluentinc/cp-schema-registry:5.5.1, confluentinc/cp-kafka-connect:5.5.1

and I'm using flink 1.12.0 and here is my docker-compose and docker file for flink:

```
services:

  jobmanager:
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      context: .
    volumes:
      - ./examples:/opt/examples
      - ./opt/flink/usrlib:/opt/flink/usrlib
    hostname: "jobmanager"
    expose:
      - "6123"
    ports:
      - "28081:8081"
    command: jobmanager
    environment:
      - JOB_MANAGER_RPC_ADDRESS=jobmanager
    networks:
      - flink-proxy-net
  taskmanager:
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      context: .
    volumes:
      - ./examples:/opt/examples
      - ./opt/flink/usrlib:/opt/flink/usrlib
    expose:
      - "6121"
      - "6122"
    depends_on:
      - jobmanager
    command: taskmanager
    links:
      - jobmanager:jobmanager
    environment:
      - JOB_MANAGER_RPC_ADDRESS=jobmanager
    networks:
      - flink-proxy-net
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM apache/flink:1.12-scala_2.11-java11

RUN set -ex 
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get -y install python3
RUN apt-get -y install python3-pip 
RUN apt-get -y install python3-dev 
RUN ln -s /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python 
RUN ln -s /usr/bin/pip3 /usr/bin/pip

RUN set -ex; 
RUN apt-get update; 
RUN python -m pip install --upgrade pip; 
RUN pip install apache-flink

ARG FLINK_VERSION=1.12.0

RUN wget -P /opt/flink/lib/ https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/flink/flink-json/${FLINK_VERSION}/flink-json-${FLINK_VERSION}.jar
RUN wget -P /opt/flink/lib/ https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/flink/flink-csv/${FLINK_VERSION}/flink-csv-${FLINK_VERSION}.jar
RUN wget -P /opt/flink/lib/ https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/flink/flink-sql-connector-kafka_2.12/${FLINK_VERSION}/flink-sql-connector-kafka_2.12-${FLINK_VERSION}.jar
RUN wget -P /opt/flink/lib/ https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/flink/flink-sql-avro/${FLINK_VERSION}/flink-sql-avro-${FLINK_VERSION}.jar

RUN mkdir -p /opt/data; \
    mkdir -p /opt/data/stream

WORKDIR /opt/flink
```

I'm trying to run a simple example of reading a topic from kafka and write data to kafka again with this python code:

```
from pyflink.datastream import StreamExecutionEnvironment
from pyflink.table import StreamTableEnvironment, EnvironmentSettings

b_s_env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.get_execution_environment()
b_s_env.set_parallelism(1)
b_s_settings = EnvironmentSettings.new_instance().use_blink_planner().in_streaming_mode().build()
b_s_t_env = StreamTableEnvironment.create(b_s_env, environment_settings=b_s_settings)
src_kafka_ddl="""
  CREATE TABLE SourceTable (
    `age` INT,
    `customer_id` INT,
    `name` STRING
  ) WITH (
    'connector' = 'kafka',
    'topic' = 'dj_customers',
    'properties.bootstrap.servers' = 'kafka1:9092',
    'properties.zookeeper.connect'='zoo1:2181',
    'scan.startup.mode' = 'earliest-offset',
    'format' = 'avro'
  )
"""
sink_kafka_ddl="""
  CREATE TABLE SinkTable (
    `customer_id` INT,
    `name` STRING
  ) WITH (
    'connector' = 'kafka',
    'topic' = 'sink_test',
    'properties.bootstrap.servers' = 'kafka1:9092',
    'properties.zookeeper.connect'='zoo1:2181',
    'scan.startup.mode' = 'earliest-offset',
    'format' = 'avro'
  )
"""

b_s_t_env.execute_sql(src_kafka_ddl)
b_s_t_env.execute_sql(sink_kafka_ddl)
orders = b_s_t_env.from_path("SourceTable") 
orders.select(orders.customer_id, orders.name).execute_insert("SinkTable").wait()
```

after submitting the job I get timeout exception

```
Caused by: org.apache.flink.kafka.shaded.org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Timeout of 60000ms expired before the position for partition _customers-0 could be determined. 

    Caused by: org.apache.flink.runtime.client.JobExecutionException: Job execution failed.
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.JobResult.toJobExecutionResult(JobResult.java:144)
        at org.apache.flink.client.deployment.ClusterClientJobClientAdapter.lambda$null$6(ClusterClientJobClientAdapter.java:123)
        ... 18 more
    Caused by: org.apache.flink.runtime.JobException: Recovery is suppressed by NoRestartBackoffTimeStrategy
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.failover.flip1.ExecutionFailureHandler.handleFailure(ExecutionFailureHandler.java:118)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.failover.flip1.ExecutionFailureHandler.getFailureHandlingResult(ExecutionFailureHandler.java:80)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.DefaultScheduler.handleTaskFailure(DefaultScheduler.java:233)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.DefaultScheduler.maybeHandleTaskFailure(DefaultScheduler.java:224)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.DefaultScheduler.updateTaskExecutionStateInternal(DefaultScheduler.java:215)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.SchedulerBase.updateTaskExecutionState(SchedulerBase.java:665)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.SchedulerNG.updateTaskExecutionState(SchedulerNG.java:89)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.JobMaster.updateTaskExecutionState(JobMaster.java:447)
        at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor41.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcActor.handleRpcInvocation(AkkaRpcActor.java:306)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcActor.handleRpcMessage(AkkaRpcActor.java:213)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.FencedAkkaRpcActor.handleRpcMessage(FencedAkkaRpcActor.java:77)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcActor.handleMessage(AkkaRpcActor.java:159)
        at akka.japi.pf.UnitCaseStatement.apply(CaseStatements.scala:26)
        at akka.japi.pf.UnitCaseStatement.apply(CaseStatements.scala:21)
        at scala.PartialFunction$class.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:123)
        at akka.japi.pf.UnitCaseStatement.applyOrElse(CaseStatements.scala:21)
        at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:170)
        at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:171)
        at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:171)
        at akka.actor.Actor$class.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:517)
        at akka.actor.AbstractActor.aroundReceive(AbstractActor.scala:225)
        at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:592)
        at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:561)
        at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:258)
        at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:225)
        at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.exec(Mailbox.scala:235)
        at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
        at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
        at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
        at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
    Caused by: org.apache.flink.kafka.shaded.org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Timeout of 60000ms expired before the position for partition _customers-0 could be determined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put your Flink services on the same Docker network as the broker

Easiest way would just use one compose file for everything

Comment: but the services are in the same proxynet and when I replace url with a nonexistent one, I got an error right before submission of the job. there is a problem with fetching topic partition metadata

Comment: Well, I cannot see your other Compose file, but the error is certainly networking related

Comment: you are right, the problem was listener docker external definition